# Inserting data into one column fails saying values in another column can't be null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't understand this misunderstanding by SQL Server.

As you can see, I'm trying to insert into column Ordamount, but SQL Server shows me in its error message that it can't insert null into column UserID?

```
Declare @variable1 int =( select sum(Orr.quantity *OI.Iteprice)
                          from Orderrouter Orr
                          inner join OrdItem OI on Orr.OrdItems =OI.ItemId
                          where OrdId = 1)

 insert into Ord (Ordamount)
 values (@variable1);
```

Error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>  Cannot insert the value
>   NULL into column 'UserID', table 'Example.dbo.Ord'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

For columns in the Ord table that does not allow null by default, you have to provide value for, you cannot skip them. You have to provide value for UserID if it's not Nullable unless it's an identity column

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you only specify the amount when inserting which isn't the primary key in the table, might be an idea to show how the table looks as well. An auto increment on the id column migh solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use a more descriptive title.

Beside this, it seems that the Ord.UserID field is not initialized. Maybe it is not an autoincrement.

Try with this, specifying the UserId value:

```
INSERT into Ord values(<UserId value here>, @Varaible1)
```